# Swift 2.0 Check if multi-dimensional array contains specific arrays

Tags: arrays, swift2

I have a set of correct combinations like following

```
[["dbc", "dbs", "dbt"], ["dyc", "dys", "dyt"], ["drc", "drs", "drt"]]
```

and was hoping to see if my combinations contain any of correct combination when my combinations are

```
[["drs", "gbc", "lrs"], ["grt", "lbc", "lbt"], ["drc", "drs", "drt"], ["dyc", "dys", "dyt"]]
```

If there are any matches, then print out correct combination.

I've tested .contains, but I guess it only works with finding one element in one-dimensional array. How can I check if multi-dimensional array contains specific arrays?

Answer (score 2):

So, in other terms, you have 2 lists of elements (where an element is an array of 3 strings) and you want to find the **intersection** of the 2 lists.

```
let corrects : Set = [["dbc", "dbs", "dbt"], ["dyc", "dys", "dyt"], ["drc", "drs", "drt"]]
let all : Set = [["drs", "gbc", "lrs"], ["grt", "lbc", "lbt"], ["drc", "drs", "drt"], ["dyc", "dys", "dyt"]]

let intersection = Array(corrects.intersect(all))

intersection // [["dyc", "dys", "dyt"], ["drc", "drs", "drt"]]
```

Hope this helps

---

P.S. The logic of my answer is similar of the one described by *egor.zhdan*. I'm just using the Swift native `Set` struct instead of the `NSSet`/`NSMutableSet` classes bridged from Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `NSMutableSet` and `intersectSet` method:

```
let correct = [["dbc", "dbs", "dbt"], ["dyc", "dys", "dyt"], ["drc", "drs", "drt"]]
let all = [["drs", "gbc", "lrs"], ["grt", "lbc", "lbt"], ["drc", "drs", "drt"], ["dyc", "dys", "dyt"]]

let correctSet = NSSet(array: correct)
let allSet = NSMutableSet(array: all)
allSet.intersectSet(correctSet as Set<NSObject>)

print(allSet) // prints (("drc", "drs", "drt"), ("dyc", "dys", "dyt"))
```